# ASP.NET CORE Apps configure with HTTPS won't load on any browser

Tags: asp.net-core, https

Every browser will throw an error called **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** when they try to load: `https://localhost:44309/`.
Here are the screenshots with their respective error from each browser:


**Firefox**
[image]


**Chrome**
[image]

**Edge**
[image]

More background:

- I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and ASP.NET CORE 3.1
- Browsers run my apps when the HTTPS is not configure.
- It was working well yesterday, but today i have to formatted my PC and since then it's not working.
- I have tried desactivate the firewall but nothing changed.

  **PD:**
- I know it's a problem with my computer but i don't want to format again because it takes lot of time.

Comment: I formatted again, it's not working dunno why.

Comment: You can try to run your project with Kestrel,and check if it can work or report an error.

Comment: I'm with @YiyiYou on this, and try also this command: dotnet dev-certs https --trust

Comment: @YiyiYou How do i run my applicationon Kestrel Web Server?. I'm really a beginner, so i don't understand much of it.I'll search for it anyway.

Comment: @RoarS. It didn't work. But i'm pretty sure it's something related to windows, since i tried to execute the app on Ubuntu 20.04 with Rider and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Did you try this: dotnet dev-certs https --trust

Comment: @RoarS. I tried with dotnet dev-certs https --trust  and didn't work either. Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.
A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to hi-jack this issue, but need to illustrate this with a pic. If you see the arrow with IIS Express, select the one with your app name and press F5

[image]

Comment: It didn't work.<br> But something strange happend, i have ubuntu 20.04 with Rider (IDE) in another partition and i tried to execute the app there and it worked. So i'm pretty sure it's something relate to windows.